# my angular js is not working after i identifiy something in my ng-app

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Angular JavaScript! </title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />




</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<div class="container">


  <input class="form-control" ng-model="Firstname" />


  {{Firstname}}




   </div> <!-- container -->




</body>

</html>
```

my script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp'. []);



app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

   $scope.Firstname = "guidy";
   $scope.Lastname = "manson";

})
```

I've been trying to find a for solution for this for hours and I just can't find any.

My problem is that the data binding suddenly isn't working after I put `ng-app="myApp"` in my Html tag. However, when I put it this way: `ng-app=""`, the data binding is already working. Can you guys figure out why angularjs data-binding is not working after I put or identify "myApp" in my ng-app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp'. []);
```

This should have a comma and not a dot

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Also add `ng-controller="myCtrl"` to your view

Answer (score 0):

you should add `ng-controller` directive to your view.

```
 <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div class="container">
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="Firstname" />
      {{Firstname}}
    </div> <!-- container -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```